# Why $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Why $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z$?

Is there a proof for this fact? Also, if I want to understand more the hom, ext, tor and tensor functors, should I study homological algebra course.

Comment: Here is a more general version of what you wish to prove: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300149/show-that-operatornamehom-r-r-m-cong-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathbb Z$ is generated by $\{1\}$, therefore $f\mapsto f(1)$ is the isomorphism.